# Do old browsers recognizes HTML5 charset format?

Tags: html, character-encoding, meta-tags, meta, html4

I read lots of information on the web, and couldn't find the answer of this quistion. If I use

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

will the coding be applied correctly in browsers that don't support HTML5?

I understand that HTML5 doesn't require closing the meta tag, but closing it seems more decent to make very old browsers at least try to understand it.

Don't know it this thought is correct, but now I wanted to know if I should include that old

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

format or not (wanting HTML4 compatibility).

Comment: 1) Define "old". 2) This shouldn't be your *primary* indicator of the charset in the first place, the HTTP `Content-Type` header takes precedence.

Comment: Old = browsers that don't support HTML5. And thus, I'm asking about the html5 shortned version, if it will be recognized by these old browsers somehow or not at all. Thanks.